# Spring Using Redis @Cacheable

Tags: java, spring, redis

Can any one suggest a Redis (NoSQL DB) example for a Collection type?
Generally we use the following (in Spring):

```
@Cacheable(value = "PRODUCT", key = "#productId" ) 
public Map<String,Object> findProduct(String productId, String productName)
 { return map; }
```

which stores the key and value as String, but I need for:

```
public Map<RestaurantId,Set<Order>>find(String RestaurantId, String productName){ return map; }
```

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your objects are Serializable, and then simply use the [Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-redis/) [Redis cache abstraction](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/redis.html#redis:support:cache-abstraction) ([2015 link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#redis:support:cache-abstraction%20spring%20redis%20cache%20abstraction))

Example copied from the documentation above:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
  xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

  <bean id="jedisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
        p:use-pool="true"/>

  <!-- redis template definition -->
  <bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate"
    p:connection-factory-ref="jedisConnectionFactory"/>

  <!-- turn on declarative caching -->
  <cache:annotation-driven />

  <!-- declare Redis Cache Manager -->
  <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager" c:template-ref="redisTemplate"/>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Redisson](https://redisson.org) Redis Java client which provides [Spring Cache](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/14.-Integration%20with%20frameworks#142-spring-cache) manager as well. It supports both `TTL` and `maxIdleTime` parameters.

Code example:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableCaching
public static class Application {

    @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
    RedissonClient redisson() throws IOException {
        Config config = new Config();
        config.useClusterServers()
              .addNodeAddress("redis://127.0.0.1:7004", "redis://127.0.0.1:7001");
        return Redisson.create(config);
    }

    @Bean
    CacheManager cacheManager(RedissonClient redissonClient) {
        Map<String, CacheConfig> config = new HashMap<String, CacheConfig>();

        // create "testMap" cache with ttl = 24 minutes and maxIdleTime = 12 minutes
        config.put("testMap", new CacheConfig(24*60*1000, 12*60*1000));
        return new RedissonSpringCacheManager(redissonClient, config);
    }

}
```